# Snowflake UDF which can be used like an infix operator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to create a snowflake UDF which can be used like an infix operator.

Basically i want to invoke the function in the following manner:

```
column_name <function> argument
```

instead of `function(column_name, argument)`.

Comment: Probably no, but why?

Comment: It is interesting question, I do not think that operator overload is possible with SQL. Are you trying to solve some specific issue(I could imagine some scenarios  when try to funciton nesting but even then I would opt for postfix(RPN) notation) :)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake UDFs do support operator overloading with the normal syntax. Both data typ and number of arguments. See the documentation, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-overview.html
I've used this often.
It doesn't support infix. FUNCTION(args,...) is pretty standard syntax in most languages. Functions are different than operators.